# Substitute cut command inside AWK script

Tags: scripts, text-processing, awk

I have a structured text file `test.tr`, and I would like to analyze it with an AWK script, but for a special reason I want to get all numbers surrounded with underscores, for example: `_0_` should become `0`. This is an example of input text file: `s 0.000000000 _0_ RTR`

So I'm trying to use the `cut` command inside the AWK script as follows:

```awk
# AWK script
BEGIN{
 # initialization
 highest_node_id = 0;
}
{
    node_id = $3
    node_id = node_id | cut -d "_" -f2 | cut -d "_" -f1 ;# this line causes error 
    if (node_id > highest_node_id) {
        highest_node_id = node_id;
    }
}
END{
 #print results
}
```

But I get an error

```
awk: `analyze.awk: line 37: syntax error at or near cut`
```

whereas the same command works OK in a bash script.

What should I do?

Comment: You should show your whole script and a sample of the input and explain the result you want.

Comment: Based on your (poor) problem statement, I suspect you should be setting an appropriate multi-character separator - or using awk's built-in `substr` or `gsub` command to remove the surrounding characters instead. See [GNU awk: String-Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

Comment: @Zanna, steeldriver
Thanks for your response, the desired modification done to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work by using `substr`:

```
tmp_node_id = $3;
node_id = substr(tmp_node_id, 2, (length(tmp_node_id) - 2));
printf ("node %s\n", node_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

`cut` works in a `bash` script, but shell is shell and `awk` is `awk`. You can't use `perl` commands in `awk` scripts either.

If you want external programs inside your script, you need to use the `system` command, but for what you seem to be doing here, you should use the string functions of `awk` like `substr` and `gensub`.

Comment: @ Philippos thanks for your response, i want to use `cut` command to extract string surrounded  with underscores, as these strings represents node id, i can't use `substr` because i don't know the total numbers of characters that represent the node id. Please give me an example of using `system` inside awk script. I try the following  but it not works `system("node_id | cut -d "_" -f2 | cut -d "_" -f1")`